# jQuery.append not working

Tags: jquery, html, append

I'm trying to iterate an array of JSON object to create a dropdown like [this](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/dropdowntree.htm?arctic) but using nested ul li. It seems this simple code is not working. It generates the ul li as expected but `.append` is not working. I'm not getting the reason. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s37y3tyu/1/)

```
<form action="save/" method="post">
    <div class="select"></div>        
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var jsn = [
    {
        "home": "Home",
        "solutions": {
            "education": "Education",
            "financial_services": "FinancialServices",
            "govt": "Government"
        },
        "products": {
            "PCProducts1": "PCPROducts1",
            "PCProducts2": "PCPROducts2",
            "PCProducts3": "PCPROducts3"
        }
    }
];

function iterObject(jsn, select){
    $.each(jsn, function(key, val){
        if(isplain(val)){
            ret = createOption(key, val);
            $(select).append(ret); //This code is not working
        }else{
            ret = createGroup(key);
            iterObject(val, ret)
        }
        console.log("ret", ret); // This prints expected output         
    });
}
function createOption(val, txt){
    return '<li rel="'+val+'">'+txt+'</li>';
}
createGroup = function (grpname){
    return  '<ul "class"="optiongroup"  "label"='+grpname+'></ul>';
};
function isplain(data){
    if (typeof data === 'number' || typeof data === 'string'){return true;}else{ return false;}
}
iterObject(jsn, '.select');
```

**NOTE UPDATE** - Code was not finished while the query was asked. So code in query will not show `ul` and `li`s nested. As of now, It should display all the`ul` n `li`s in `.select`.

Comment: Why is there a  forward slash in your form action?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin - I'm using python -django, I don't think that has anything to do with the query.

Comment: did you tried to log `ret`? put this code before append. `console.log(ret);`

Comment: could you please check for $(select).size() if it is 1 ? and if $(select) is an element or an array?

Comment: @RubenYeghikyan - Tried that no luck

Comment: @morels - Yse the size is 1 also an element not an array

Comment: @Pete, In each iteration it is being called again. I guess thats the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the selector:

```
$('.select').append(ret);
```

Also, You would need to var scope 'ret' variable as below:

```
function iterObject(jsn, select){
var ret; 
//Rest of the code
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s37y3tyu/2/)

Comment: it makes all <li> tags go into <div>. Where are the <ul>'s?

Comment: @AntonF, No it's not his fault. My code has not  finished yet. I guess its output is correct.

Comment: Declaring variables is important, but this is not the solution. "Declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top". He calls "iterObject" inside the "each" fn. It makes no difference if he has the var statement at the function top. Check out "var hoisting" @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Yes, I agree adding var is not the solution. Correct usage of selector is the solution. Along, with the solution I just highlighted the issue in code.

Comment: @MehulSaiya Yes, agree with u. The correct usage of selector is the solution. You could have highlighted the issue suggestion before proposing him to add variable statement, avoiding "also" word before your real answer. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Now it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/2kd0p25n/

```
function iterObject(jsn, select){
    $.each(jsn, function(key, val){
        if(isplain(val)){
            ret = createOption(key, val);
            $(".optiongroup").last().append(ret);
        }else{
            ret = createGroup(key);
            $(select).append(ret);
            iterObject(val, '.select')
        }         
    });
}
function createOption(val, txt){
    return '<li rel="'+val+'">'+txt+'</li>';
}
createGroup = function (grpname){
    return  '<ul class="optiongroup"  "label"='+grpname+'></ul>';
};
function isplain(data){
    if (typeof data === 'number' || typeof data === 'string'){return true;}else{ return false;}
}
iterObject(jsn, '.select');
```

Comment: First of all. The <ul> tags never get appended. This makes <li> tags go nowhere. Then, the original '.select' selector will be used on only the first iteration. Which is wrong also.

Comment: @AntonF -Great! +1 for your code `.last().append()`, This made my work more easy. I was about to use `if else` to achieve that.

Comment: @RayonDabre - Don't mind, But I have asked this query because my code was not working. I think Mehul pointed out the actual bug in my code. Also I appreciate AntonF's answer. It saved my lot of time. But can't accept two answers at a time.

Comment: @Laxmikant, you  certainly can not accept 2 answers but you need to consider the efforts and quality of answer while accepting. Getting all the `li` elements was not the intention of the code anyways..

Comment: @RayonDabre - Even my code in the query also will do the same, showing all the `li`s in `select` only. As I had mentioned earlier that the code hasn't finished yet,  till then I was working on that.

Comment: No, It would not. One could easily make out the purpose of `createGroup`

Comment: @RayonDabre - Updated note in the query.

Comment: I don't agree that the proposed code is recursively method well applied. But plus one cause you've distinguished $(".optiongroup") from $('.select') when interacting.

Comment: @angellica.araujo - I agree that recursion is not well applied. I just wanted to achieve goal without any complexion in it. It was the easiest way to get each key-value of a json.

Comment: @Laxmikant Hello. No problem with your code. I belive that we are expected  to rewrite code in order to write it better and better ... If I had a better idea than AntonF (or yours) I could have answered your question :) However, you should consider AntonF as the final answer, in my opnion. AntonF do really work with yours selectors in the right way ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterObject(jsn, select){
   $.each(jsn, function(key, val){
        if(isplain(val)){
           ret = createOption(key, val);
           $(select).append(jQuery(ret)); //This code is not working
       }
       else{
           ret = createGroup(key);
           var jQret = jQuery(ret);
           jQuery(select).append(jQret );
           iterObject(val, jQret);
       }
       console.log("ret", ret); // This prints expected output
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is interesting as it is related with recursion. Here is my code

JS

```
var jsn = [
    {
        "home": "Home",
        "solutions": {
            "education": "Education",
            "financial_services": "FinancialServices",
            "govt": "Government"
        },
        "products": {
            "PCProducts1": "PCPROducts1",
            "PCProducts2": "PCPROducts2",
            "PCProducts3": "PCPROducts3"
        }
    }
];

var menuBuilder = (function() {

    var isLeaf= function(obj) {
        return typeof obj !=='object';
    };

    var buildItems = function(objlist) {
        var expected= '';
        var items;

        $.each(objlist, function(key, val) {      

            if(!isLeaf(val)) {
                items= buildItems(val);

                expected+= '<li>' + key;
                expected+= '<ul>' + items + '</ul>';
                expected+= '</li>';
            } else {
                expected+= '<li>' + val + '</li>';
            }
        });

        return expected;
    };    

    var read = function(json) {
        var items= buildItems(json);
        var expect= '';

        if(items==='') return expect;

        expect += '<ul>';
        expect += items;
        expect += '</ul>';

        return expect;
    };

    return {
        read: read
    };

})();


$('#container').append(menuBuilder.read(jsn[0]));
```

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```